# Qualitative understanding of excess heat capacity in ferroics

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, material-science, dielectric

I'm looking to understand what an excess heat capacity in a ferroelectric (FE) can correspond to qualitatively. Typically one starts with a Landau expansion of the free energy if you want to study the thermodynamics of a FE; in 1D for simplicity:

$$F = \alpha_1 (T-T_C) P^2 + \alpha_{11} P^4 + \alpha_{112} P^6 - E P$$

with

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial P} = 0 \,\,\,\mathrm{and}\,\,\,\, \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial P^2} > 0 $$

representing the equilibrium condition. Solving the above for $P$ at constant $T$ and then substituting that back in the free energy gives $F^0$ where

$$S^\mathrm{XS} = - \frac{\partial F^0}{\partial T}$$

is the excess entropy and

$$\Delta C^\mathrm{XS}_V = - T \frac{\partial^2 F^0}{\partial T^2}$$

is the excess heat capacity. This quantity is usually largest right before the phase transition. See, as an example $\mathrm{BaTiO}_3$ at 0% strain and zero applied field (loosely following the work in J. Appl Phys. $\mathbf{103}$, 024104 2008) -- Here $C_V$ obtained from VDOS DFT calculations as opposed to the work in that paper. Note $T_C = 383\, \mathrm{K}$.

[image]

Also, note that these quantities are just due to the ferroelectricity. I certainly understand why there is an excess entropy. The dipoles can be ordered below the transition temperature and thus will contribute negatively to the total entropy than if the material is paraelectric.

However, I'm trying to wrap my head around the physics of the excess heat capacity. Why is does it cost more heat to increase the temperature of the ferroelectric near the phase transition? What is the physical process here?

Comment: Without putting a full answer in, the heat capacity changes near the phase transition in part due to the change in crystal structure. BaTiO3 is a great example: it changes from rhombohedral to orthorhombic to tetragonal to cubic with increasing temperature.  With each change in crystal structure, the symmetry increases up to the parent phase.  As the symmetry changes, the number of available vibration modes increases, and so, heat capacity also changes.

Comment: So it's due to the Jahn-Teller effect?

Comment: Wait, this can't be the explanation. $C_V$ is found from VDOS calculations which doesn't show a considerable spike at the phase transition, this $\Delta C_V^{XS}$ is completely due to the ferroelectricity, and is calculated from the calorimetric equation of state $S = - \frac{\partial G}{\partial T} \Rightarrow \Delta C_V^{XS} = - T \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial T^2}$ so how would the vibrational modes cause this? I was told that the soft-mode might have some contribution.